# CKAN: automatically delete datastore tables when a resource is removed

Tags: datastore, ckan

I have a ckan instance configured with the filestore, datastore and datapusher plugins enabled.

When I create a new resource, the datapusher plugin correctly adds a new table to the datasoredb and populates it with the data.

But if I update the resource, a new datapusher task is executed and everything updates correctly. On another ckan instance with a resource linked to it, I have to manually run the task, but everything works ok.

The problem comes if I delete the resource. The datastore tables are still available, and even the link to the file is still active.

Is there some way to configure it to autoremove every trace of the resource??? I mean, remove the files from the filestore, the tables from the datastore, the api, the links, etc.

Comment: What version of CKAN are you using. Depending on the version, this may or may not be possible.

Comment: We're using 2.2.1 and would love to have this resolved. Anyone wondering what version they have can find out from http://<YOUR CKAN DOMAIN>/api/util/status.

Comment: Maybe you need to make a call to Datastore API to delete the resource

Comment: @opensas did you figure this out? I just got into ckan a few weeks ago and now i realize that when i delete a resource, the file is still there, somewhere. did you manage to delete the file from the system?

Answer (score 0):

I partially confirmed this behaviour with http://demo.ckan.org, which is currently ckan_version: "2.4.1"

1. Create a resource
2. Query resource via data pusher
3. Delete resource
4. Query resource via datastore_search API -> still works can query.
5. Attempt to access resource file ->  404 - not found.

Will file as bug.

Perhaps use this to delete ?http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html#ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_delete

Answer (score 0):

This is possible through CLI:

`sudo -u postgres psql datastore_default`
(assumes datastore installed from package using [these Datastore Extension settings](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html) and database name is `datastore_default`and `postgres` is superuser).

THEN (OPTIONAL TO FIND ALL RESOURCE UUID's):

`\dt` to list all tables

THEN:

`DROP TABLE "{RESOURCE ID}";`

(Replace {RESOURCE ID} with resource UUID)